# Welche Bedeutung hat "drangeben"?

Tags: word-usage, colloquial, spelling, regional

In einem Roman las ich folgenden Satz:

> Sie hatte versucht, sich mit ihm zu unterhalten, hatte das aber bald **drangegeben**.

Ist das ein regionaler Ausdruck für **aufgeben**, bzw. **klein beigeben** oder einfach eine Falschschreibung von [**dreingeben**](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/dreingeben)? In welcher Region ist diese Bedeutung dann gebräuchlich?

Ginge man nach dem Duden, würde das Wort [drangeben](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/drangeben) (hingeben, opfern) in dem Zusammenhang nicht passen. Meine alten Dudenausgaben führen das Wort nicht einmal auf (1930, 1964).

Answer (score 4):

Richtig, *drangeben* heißt *aufgeben*.

Der Zusammenhang *etwas drangeben/ etwas opfern/ etwas aufgeben* ist auch nicht so falsch, auch wenn im Beispiel mit der Unterhaltung das Opfern nicht passt.

Zur räumlichen Zuordnung kann ich wenig sagen. Mir scheint, ich hätte es bei BAP schon gehört, einer Kölner Band, was zu Em1s ripuarischen Dialekten passen würde, aber mir fällt der Song nicht mehr ein - vielleicht war es ja auch ein Interview oder eine Ansage zu einem Song - eine Onlinesuche hilft mir jedenfalls nicht weiter.

Comment: Danke erst einmal, daß Du Dir die Zeit genommen hast du antworten. Schade, Takkat hatte leider eine Bemerkung von mir heraus editiert. Bis auf diesen Lapsus war seine Bearbeitung allerdings passend. Ich hatte noch bemerkt, daß **dreingeben** im Duden nicht nur aufgeführt ist, sondern sogar in der gebrauchten Bedeutung und vermutet, daß es sich simpel um eine Falschschreibung handeln könnte. Denn ich muß gestehen, mir war diese Wortbedeutung bisher nicht geläufig.

Answer (score 2):

Bei uns im Meller/Osnabrücker Raum bedeutet es auch „einen Dienst beenden“, etwa im Alter von 75 Jahren mit einer Tätigkeit aufgeben; aber „drangeben“ klingt positiver als „aufgeben“. Ich denke es klingt wie wenn man irgend hinter etwas herjagt, dann aber „es dran gibt“.

Comment: Eine furchtbare Unsitte Begriffe immer als `positiv` und `negativ` kategorisieren zu wollen. Das Ziel die Eigerwand zu besteigen dranzugeben - ist das positiv oder negativ? Den Job als Drücker drangeben - positiv oder negativ? Positiv oder negativ für wen?